# Java: Button isn't showing up

Tags: java, swing

So, i'm using Java and JFrame and i would like the end user to be able to click the button "Login" and it should display another saying "Edit". For some odd reason when the end-user clicks "Login" it doesn't show the "Edit" box but it displays the "System.out.println"

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends  JFrame{

    public void fixtureList()
    {
        JButton editButton;

        editButton = new JButton("Edit");
        editButton.setBounds(100, 200, 100, 100);
        add(editButton);

    }

    public void loginPanel()
    {
        setLayout(null);

        JButton loginButton;

        loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        loginButton.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 100);
        add(loginButton);
        loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                //Execute when button is pressed
                fixtureList();
                System.out.println("Loading the fixtures screen");
            }

        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Main window = new Main();

        window.setTitle("PE Fixtures v1.0");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(250, 430);
        window.loginPanel();
        window.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(53, 56, 64));
        window.setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `revalidate()` after you add the button?

Comment: I added that below   public void fixtureList()
    {
        JButton editButton;

        editButton = new JButton("Edit");
        editButton.setBounds(100, 200, 100, 100);
        add(editButton);

Comment: Remember to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` in the main. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/HelloWorldSwingProject/src/start/HelloWorldSwing.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `repaint` in the `ActionListener`

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //Execute when button is pressed
        fixtureList();
        System.out.println("Loading the fixtures screen");
        repaint();
    }
```